# Can you have Load Controller and Load Injector on the same machine?

Tags: loadrunner, load-generator

Is it possible to have have HP Load Runner (Controller/Analysis/VU Gen) and HP Load Injector (Generator) on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but this is considered a poor practice and is not recommended.

As a person who audits a lot of performance tests I would have to bring up all sorts of concerns (independent of tool) that come into play.  I like to see at least three matched generators with one used as a control generator and the other two for primary load.  This is in addition to the host for the controller.

Realistically, independent of tool, if the financial risk of application failure is high enough to warrant a performance test then the cost of load generators is a boil on a mosquito's butt from a total cost perspective